# Reading Json file and converting it to columns in python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to read [this json file](https://github.com/ansymo/msr2013-bug_dataset/blob/master/data/v02/mozilla/short_desc.json) in python using this code (I want to have all the data in a data frame):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json 
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = pd.read_json('short_desc.json')
df.head()
```

[Data frame head screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAuY6.png)

using this code I am able to convert only the first row to separated columns:

```
json_normalize(df.short_desc.iloc[0])
```

[First row screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZXJg.png)

I want to do the same for whole df using this code:

```
df.apply(lambda x : json_normalize(x.iloc[0]))
```

but I get this error:

> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

What I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

After reading the json file with `json.load`, you can use `pd.DataFrame.from_records`.  This should create the DataFrame you are looking for.

```
wih open('short_desc.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(d)
```

Comment: It gives me a dataset which has a Json column, I am trying to convert the json to columns. Look at this https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAuY6.png, I want to have seprated columns for when, what and who

Comment: What does your json look like?

Comment: If you want to use `json_normalize`, pass it `d` from my answer above.  Without seeing your JSON data it's hard to say what's going on.

Comment: here is the JSON file :)   https://github.com/ansymo/msr2013-bug_dataset/blob/master/data/v02/mozilla/short_desc.json